# Find out how many NATs exist between my home machine and the Internet

Tags: nat

Are there any tools/utilities that can help me find out how many NATs exist between my home machine and the public Internet?

Any references to protocols that would help me figure this out would also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I thought traceroute (linux) provides the list of routers that are encountered while a packet travels from a source to destination. But it doesn't necessarily mean that each router has an integrated NAT component.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: On Windows use `tracert` instead.

Comment: I believe tracert on Windows is equivalent to traceroute on linux. Is it not so?

Answer (score 1):

Start > Run > type `cmd` to open a Command Prompt. Enter the following command:

```
tracert www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Some SOHO routers will show your connections and the associated ports.  You won't be able to get the information from routers in the Internet.  On Windows you can view your connections by typing the following in a Command Prompt:

```
netstat
```